# BrowserVersion, UserLanguages , Request.Url in vb .net core 2.2

Tags: vb.net, http, browser, .net-core

I am converting my vb.net solution to .net core 2.2. Some VB functions are not supported by .Net core. I have to convert the below code and some of them  is not supported by .net core 2.2 . Is there any way to convert the code ?

Thanks in Advance

{

```
             lBrowserVersion = current.Request.Browser.Version 
             Dim langs As String() = current.Request.UserLanguages()
              lPageUrl = current.Request.Url.ToString()
```

}

Comment: Did you try Googling the answer?

Comment: yeah I tried but didn't get anything positive .